# Becket oil fired furnace blower won’t kick on

Tags: hvac, furnace

So I’m having problems with the blower in my furnace. I can get it to light and it gets a good flame, but the blower won’t kick on. I’ve replaced the limit switch and took the motor off to see if it worked or not, the motor is fine. Any advice? I will try to answer any other questions the best I can.